# Google visualisation load failed - error

Tags: google-visualization, googlevis

I have some complex google visualisation code and sometimes table show perfectly and sometimes I get this screen:

[image]

What mean that error? I look on google search but I cant get any answer? What that mean?

How sometimes google visualisation table load fine and sometimes not?
Maybe problem can be my database data, becouse I have an cell with words separated by (,) comma ... I get this like string...

**UPDATE: this is my js code for google visualisation:**
http://jsbin.com/binuvawi/1/edit

**UPDATE 2:**
sample of getzadaci.php :

```
{"cols":[{"label":"ID","type":"number"},{"label":"Naziv","type":"string"},{"label":"Vrsta","type":"string"},{"label":"Status","type":"string"},{"label":"Opis","type":"string"},{"label":"Pocetak","type":"date"},{"label":"Zavrsetak","type":"date"},{"label":"Odgovoran","type":"string"},{"label":"Parcela","type":"string"},{"label":"Usluzno?","type":"string"},{"label":"id_parcele","type":"string"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":1},{"v":"Priprema"},{"v":"navodnjavanje"},{"v":"U pripremi"},{"v":"Da se izrzi nadovdnjavanje"},{"v":"Date(2014, 02, 25)"},{"v":"Date(2014, 02, 28)"},{"v":"Laza Lazic"},{"v":"Njiva 5"},{"v":"NE"},{"v":"0"}]},{"c":[{"v":2},{"v":"Djubrenje"},{"v":"djubrenje"},{"v":"U toku"},{"v":"Vrsi se djubrenje parcele na temp. od oko 12C"},{"v":"Date(2014, 02, 28)"},{"v":"Date(2014, 03, 05)"},{"v":"Pera Peric"},{"v":"vocnjak 3"},{"v":"DA"},{"v":"0"}]},{"c":[{"v":22},{"v":"Novo zemljiste"},{"v":"obrada tla, zastita, berba\/zetva "},{"v":"Zavrseno"},{"v":"jeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee"},{"v":"Date(2013, 04, 30)"},{"v":"Date(2013, 05, 11)"},{"v":""},{"v":"S4"},{"v":"787"},{"v":"0"}]},{"c":[{"v":25},{"v":"sklas"},{"v":"obrada tla, zastita, skladistenje"},{"v":"U planu"},{"v":"testiranje"},{"v":"Date(2013, 04, 17)"},{"v":"Date(2013, 04, 30)"},{"v":""},{"v":"Vocnjak N, S4, Moja parcela N, Parcela 3n "},{"v":""},{"v":"3, 19, 11, 13"}]}]}
```

**LOAD:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['controls']});

      </script>
```

Comment: also when I call function that draw table - drawVisualization();
 then table is here, so table is visibl and without error...

Comment: There are a large number of things that could cause that error; post a code sample that replicates the problem and I'll take a look to see if I can figure out what might be causing this.

Comment: I update question with google viz code: http://jsbin.com/binuvawi/1/edit ... also I want to say that when I load page I get that error but then if I call drawVisualisation function in browser console then work fine , so without error

Comment: I don't see a call to `google.load` (I assume you have one, otherwise you wouldn't get as far as those error messages); can you update the jsbin code with that call?  Also, if you would post some sample data returned by the AJAX call to `getzadaci.php`, it would help me test the code.

Comment: I update my question with getzadaci.php sample and with google viz LOAD...

Comment: I made an [example based on your code](http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/mwQ9t/) and I can't replicate the problem.  Do you see any errors when you view that (other than ones related to selecting table rows - I did not implement the requisite HTML to make those work)?

Comment: I change version google visualisation from 1.1 to 1.0 and now work fine :) ... thanks for helping me